# Specify a file name in http headers while sending file to client via http

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express

I have a JS Array that I convert into a CSV format in the Server and send to the client by setting `Content-Type: text/csv`

When I send it to the client, the browser automatically downloads the file, with the file name as the last part of the URL.

**For example:**
If the link is `/link/to/generated_csv`, then `generated_csv` is automatically taken as the file name.
How do I specify that the file name as `downloaded_csv.csv`?

I am using Node.js and Express.js.

```js
router.get("/link/to/generated_csv") = function(req, res) {
    let generated_csv = array2csv(source_js_array);
    res.set("Content-Type", "text/csv");
    // Something here to set a file name??
    return res.send(generated_csv);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is usually done with the [Content-Disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header.

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded_csv.csv"
```

Comment: And `Content-Disposition: Attachment; Filename*=UTF-8'de'an%20example` for different languages/characters. See https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-content-disp-02.xml

Answer (score 1):

Include content-Disposition in `res.set()`

```
res.set({
    "Content-Disposition": 'attachment; filename="downloaded_csv.csv"',
    "Content-Type": "text/csv",
});
```